# How to make a self playing snake game using JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code a snake game that will randomly move through the canvas. for now, I won't worry about the "food" as my main problem is the self-playing part not running. it seems to start but does not change course over time, so not sure if need to implement a timer (?)

Tried with a switch and thought by generating with `random()` one of the alternatives but only goes in one direction until hits the border

```
        */<-------------------------HTML----------------------->*/



<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

 </head>
 <body>
  <div class= 'game'>
  <div id = 'home'>
    <canvas id='mycanvas' width='350' height='350'>
    </canvas>
    </div>

    <button id='btn'>START</button>
  </div>

  <script src="js/logic.js"></script>

 </body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
    /*<----------------------CSS----------------------->*/

    #home {
          width: 350px;
          height: 350px;

          background-size: auto 350px;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-color: lightgrey;
          background-position: center center;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 03;

        }

        button {
          background-color: green;
          color: white;
          border: none;
          bottom: 0;
          height: 30px;
          font-size: 12pt;
          float: left;
          width: 90px;
          margin: 10px 0 0 0;
        }
        button:hover {
          background-color: darkgreen;
        }

        button:disabled {
          background-color: grey;
        }



        .game {
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

**JS:**

```
/*<-------------------JS----------------->*/




    var mycanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
var snakeSize = 10;
var w = 350;
var h = 350;
var snake;
var snakeSize = 10;
var pixel;

var drawModule = (function() {

    var bodySnake = function(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fillRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.strokeRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
    }



    var drawSnake = function() {
        var length = 4;
        snake = [];
        for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            snake.push({ x: i, y: 0 });
        }
    }
    var paint = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'lightgrey';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);

        btn.setAttribute('disabled', true);

        var snakeX = snake[0].x;
        var snakeY = snake[0].y;

        if (direction == 'right') {
            snakeX++;
        } else if (direction == 'left') {
            snakeX--;
        } else if (direction == 'up') {
            snakeY--;
        } else if (direction == 'down') {
            snakeY++;
        }

        if (snakeX == -1 || snakeX == w / snakeSize || snakeY == -1 || snakeY == h / snakeSize || checkCollision(snakeX, snakeY, snake)) {

            btn.removeAttribute('disabled', true);

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            gameloop = clearInterval(gameloop);
            return;
        }

        if (snakeX == pixel.x && snakeY == pixel.y) {
            var tail = { x: snakeX, y: snakeY };

        } else {
            var tail = snake.pop();
            tail.x = snakeX;
            tail.y = snakeY;
        }

        snake.unshift(tail);

        for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
            bodySnake(snake[i].x, snake[i].y);
        }


    }


    var createPixels = function() {
        pixel = {
            x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1),
            y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1)
        }
    }

    var checkCollision = function(x, y, array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].x === x && array[i].y === y) {
                return true;
                //this part should reinitiate the game
                //when it hits an edge
                /*}
                if (x > w - 1 || x < 0 || y > h - 1 || h < 0) {
                    return true;*/

            }
            return false;

        }

    }

    var init = function() {
        var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);

        switch (r) {

            case 1:
                direction = 'left';
                console.log('left');
                break;

            case 2:
                direction = 'right';
                console.log('right');

                break;

            case 3:
                direction = 'up';
                console.log('up');

                break;

            case 4:
                direction = 'down';
                console.log('down');

                break;
        }
        drawSnake();
        createPixels();
        gameloop = setInterval(paint, 80);
    }


    return {
        init: init
    };


}());


(function(window, document, undefined) {

        var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
        btn.addEventListener("click", function() { drawModule.init(); });


    }


)(window, document, drawModule);
```

Comment: I recommend using the HTML/code editor, and trying to make a working example we can replicate to try and help you better.

Comment: @FrankerZ that's probably my problem. I haven't found a working example of it.
I do have an example of a regular snake game but instead of telling it where I want it to go I want it to move randomly 
[link]https://github.com/castroant/entering-darkmatter/blob/master/snake%20game.zip

Comment: No, like on stackoverflow, edit your post, and try to copy/paste what you have into an example we can copy to our answers, instead of just a simple code block.

Comment: @FrankerZ like this?

Comment: I think you added the wrong HTML part, since it refers to Hangman and the canvas's id is `#stickman`, while you are trying to access `#mycanvas` in the script part.

Comment: Edit your post, and press Ctrl+M. It will popup with 4 windows where you can put all the code, and you can test it out in the window to make a working example.

Comment: @Fitzi sorry. Long night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `direction` a random value inside the `paint()` function.

**Explanation:** Currently, the only call to `random()` is in the `init()` function, which is only called once. Thus direction is only set once, and there is no way for it to change.